# Virtualbox boot order is not preserved

Tags: boot, virtualbox, kubuntu

- Guest: Kubuntu (Ubuntu)
- Host: Kubuntu (Ubuntu) in VirtualBox VM 6.1.10_Ubuntu r138449 linux.amd64
- CD: ISO of Kubuntu Live CD (Ubuntu)

i installed Kubuntu from Kubuntu Live CD (ISO).

later live CD is ignored if i reboot the guest.

Any Idear?

Some parts of the Logfile:

```
VirtualBox VM 6.1.10_Ubuntu r138449 linux.amd64 (Jun  6 2020 11:31:37) release log
Build Type: release
OS Product: Linux
OS Release: 5.4.0-48-generic
OS Version: #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020
Firmware type: BIOS
Host RAM: 32127MB (31.3GB) total, 27132MB (26.4GB) available
Installed Extension Packs
File system of '/home/m/Downloads/kubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' (DVD) is ext4
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't say for certain, I am only guessing, but this is good. Normally the live USB/CD should be removed so after the installation you can boot into the newly installed system instead of the USB/CD.

Comment: Yes. It always Boot into the installed system. That's what I don't want

Comment: But it's what everyone else wants, so virtual box has probably turned it into a feature was the idea of my comment.